# Can we convert a model which contains events to a json string?

Tags: c#, json, stringify

I have a model with a event which is fired if something has been changed in the property.

I am trying to convert that model to json string to simplify the cloning process. I need a deep copy of that model without creating by myself. To do that I thought serialize and deserialize does what I expect but events are not converted. Can you please suggest me if this could be possible anyway in this approach?

```
public class Model{
   public string PropertyA { get; set;}
   public event EventHandler PropertyAChanged;      
}
```

Here  the propertyA is  serialized and deserialized properly but not at all the PropertyAChanged event. Model contains lot of properties and this model is like a datacontext for UI control.

Comment: You can serialize a class into a JSON string, sure, but you're not going to be able to serialize the _event_ member. Events have no knowledge of who is set up to receive the event.

Comment: @JohanDonne the list of subscribers is indeed part of the state of the instance. It is non-serializable but it does not make it to be outside of an object.